# No event context active - RESTeasy, Seam

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, jboss, resteasy, seam

I'm trying to add a RESTful web service with RESTeasy to our application running on JBoss 7.x, using Seam2.

I wanted to use as little Seam as possible, but I need it for Dependancy Injection.

My REST endpoints are as follows:

```
@Name("myEndpoint")
@Stateless
@Path("/path")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON+"; charset=UTF-8")
public class MyEndpoint {
  @In private FooService fooService;

  @GET
  @Path("/foo/{bar}")
  public Response foobar(@CookieParam("sessionId") String sessionId, 
                             @PathParam("bar") String bar)
  { ... }
}
```

I'm using a class extending `Application`. There is no XML config.
I can use the web service methods and they work, but I always get an `IllegalStateException`:

```
Exception processing transaction Synchronization after completion: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No event context active
```

[Complete StackTrace](http://pastebin.com/HndS1HTJ)

I did try everything in the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.com/seam/2.1.2/reference/en-US/html/webservices.html#d0e21974), but I can't get it away. If I leave out the `@Stateless` annotation, I don't get any Injection done. Adding `@Scope` doesn't do jack. Accessing the service via `seam/resource/` doesn't even work (even without the Application class with `@ApplicationPath`).

<s>It goes away if I don't use Dep. Injection, but instead add to *each and every method*</s>

```
fooService = Component.getInstance("fooService");
Lifecycle.beginCall();
...
Lifecycle.endCall();
```

which isn't really a good solution. Nah, doesn't work either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. For some reason (still not sure why, maybe because I tried to use Annotations and code exclusivly and no XML config), my REST service was availiable under a "non-standard" URL.

Usually it'd be something like "/seam/resources/rest".

Anyway, if you have a "custom" path, Seam doesn't know it should inject a context. You need to add `<web:context-filter url-pattern="something" />` to your `component.xml`.

Specifically we already had this tag, but with the attribute `regex-url-pattern` and I extended it to match the REST URL.